# Replacing X-ray or any radiation generating vacuum tubes with solid-state alternatives?

Tags: vacuum-tube, radiation, solid-state-devices

What are the reasons X-ray vacuum tubes could not be replaced by solid state alternatives?

I'm thinking if it is possible to make a compact solid-state X-ray or higher energy photons generator just like how vacuum tube amplifiers, computers, etc. are going to be replaced by solid-state amplifiers, computers, etc. but not 100% replaced as we can still find vacuum tube amplifiers everywhere but vacuum tube computers are already very rare.

But if I have to form the reason why vacuum tubes are still used to generate high energy radiations instead of solid-state devices with my own reasoning (although I have very limited background in physics), high speed electrons are only possible if there is some kind of chamber inside. So, common sense tells us that there is a need to include a chamber inside that thing so electrons can move freely instead of flowing through solids that will pose many difficulties.

Comment: How do you know they can't be replaced? What research have you done about the subject?

Comment: you basically asked exactly the same way before, and the reasons are mostly the same. In this new question of yours, you don't even show any additional research since that previous question, nor a glimpse of understanding the answers you've gotten. This bodes badly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you didn't give any reasons why solid-state alternatives are kind of useless, and your tone is always a little bit aggressive too especially when responding to me. Can you give detailed explanations why X-ray tubes are still used instead of solid-state alternatives?

Comment: Yes, could you name the X-ray generating solid state device you're referring to?

Comment: @MarcusMüller so far I just found this https://www.amptek.com/internal-products/cool-x-pyroelectric-x-ray-generator. But if you clicked on the theory of operation, it still looks like a tube as it have low pressure gas inside it. Maybe I guess it is common sense to include some kind of chamber so the electrons can move freely instead of flowing through solids? Is that the reason?

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah I think I'll have to just refer to Justme's comment above: you're trying to outsource your initial research to us. What sense does the question "why don't we use rubber boots to generate X-ray instead of vacuum tubes" make, seeing that rubber boots don't emit X-rays. Solid state devices don't do that, in general.

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah you even *recognized that yourself* [in a comment to your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520270/why-most-particle-accelerators-used-vacuum-diodes-instead-of-transistors#comment1336698_520270), where you literally said "Oh, they don't generate high-energy radiation at all". This question is really about the same topic, and you make zero references to your previous question and the things you've learned from the comments and the answer there. Don't know how to help you learn if you don't incorporate the things that you've learned.

Comment: @MarcusMüller first let me tell you, I just happened to be interested in how vacuum tubes and solid-state electronics work in generating electrons and then the electrons hit a tantalum target to generate high energy bremsstrahlung although I have very little understanding in engineering as I'm not an engineering student. Can you give the reasons why solid-state devices can't emit bremsstrahlung radiation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115375/discussion-between-mohamed-obeidallah-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: Can you give me a reason why rubber boots don't emit bremsstrahlung? There's no high-speed electrons. I mean, why should they? This question makes no sense!

Comment: @MarcusMüller then give detailed responses as why vacuum tubes are more suitable in generating bremsstrahlung than solid-state devices so I can understand why? Just by giving a short answer, it didn't do anything.

Comment: As said, you already understood why: their purpose is to produce high-speed electrons, that's it. Solid state devices don't. Ducks, rubber boots, ships, coffee and a lot of other things don't do that. You don't intend to ask me why ducks can't be used to produce X-ray. Yet, you seem to insist that someone explain why solid state devices don't do that, even though you put zero effort into showing that they *should*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller right. Let me form the reason with my own reasoning then. High speed electrons are only possible if there is some kind of chamber inside, so common sense tells us that there is a need to include a chamber inside that thing so electrons can move freely instead of flowing through solids that will pose many difficulties. Correct?

Comment: yes, that sounds correct, and also, this sounds like it should be **part of your question text**, not written in a comment after we asked you a million times to explain why you think solid state devices are capable of doing that. Please **edit** your question to explain your full train of thought.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you. Now I gained a little bit understanding of why solid-state devices are not suitable in generating high energy bremsstrahlung. Sorry I will try to form a more comprehensible question next time.

Comment: you didn't add what you said in your comment to your question. Your considerations are important, not only your question!

Comment: @MarcusMüller it will makes that I already answered my own question but okay I will add that.

Answer (score 1):

Semiconductors or actually the electrons which have a role in the conducting of the current operate within so narrow energy level variation range that no emitted photons can get high enough energy to be in X-ray wavelength range when an electron falls to lower energy state. To get energetic enough transitions we should have a solid semiconductor material with hundreds of times wider gap between the valence band and the conduction band than in our current materials.

To generate X-rays with DC in solid material needs probably a new principle or the ordinary long wavelength radiation maybe could be converted to X-rays. I am not a physicist so I have no idea how for ex. the conversion laser could work in X-rays because ordinary mirrors at least are useless.

Comment: So, at least large gaps are needed to separate the conduction and valence band so the electrons can move much more freely. Then, high energy photons such as X-ray and beyond can be easily generated. Thus, adding some kind of cavity is necessary even when we are using solid-state devices to generate such radiations. Like this https://www.amptek.com/internal-products/cool-x-pyroelectric-x-ray-generator. Is that correct?

Comment: The pyroelectric X-ray generator IS a new principle, totally different than what happens in LEDs. See this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/31979522_Pyroelectric_X-ray_generator  About semiconductors: Diamond is quite a wide gap material that can be a semiconductor. But something much wider is needed. BTW the gap isn't a cavity inside material, it's a zone in the energy state diagram of the material. Read some solid state physics or elementary semiconductor theory in undergraduate academic level.

Comment: How about this https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Conduction_band? Is it possible to combine an insulator with a semiconductor to prevent the issue that semiconductors have when it comes to generating high energy photons?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a scientist, I can connect and burn electronic components and sometimes I succeed to guess right how a circuit works. Your question needs a solid state physics aware scientist to answer. I must be happy with available components. I really have no idea how to calculate what electron state structure become possible by somehow mixing insulator and semiconductor.

Comment: Nevermind it's okay. Thanks again for your responses!